# TabLayout, NavigationDrawer, Toolbar

Tags: android

Мне нужно на одной активности отобразить `TabLayout`, `NavigationDrawer`, `Toolbar`. На данный момент у меня имеется 3 xml-разметки: `drawer`, `toolbar` и `tabLayour`. В `activity` сразу имеется `drawer`, а остальные 2 я подключаю через инклуд. Лучший результат - дравер и тоолбар. Как мне отобразить все три элемента. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Неясно в чём ваша проблема. Совместите все разметки полчите то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Привиде пример того, что у вас не получается и почему это происходит. Из текущего вопроса проблема не ясна.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если не сложно, можно простенький листинг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример того, что вам надо [тут](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример по D[rawer'у](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android) 
Вот пример по [toolbar](https://habrahabr.ru/post/256643/)
Вот пример по [tablayout](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)
Вам нужно все это совместить вместе, как уже ответили выше.